# Trying to match possible tags in string by regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

those are my possible inputs:

```
"@smoke"
"@smoke,@Functional1" (OR condition)
"@smoke,@Functional1,@Functional2" (OR condition)
"@smoke","@Functional1" (AND condition),  
"@smoke","~@Functional1" (SKIP condition), 
"~@smoke","~@Functional1" (NOT condition)
```

(Please note, the string input for the regex, stops at the last `"` character on each line, no space or comma follows it!

The regex I came up with so far is

```
"((?:[~@]{1}\w*)+),?"
```

This matches in capturing groups for the samples 1, 4, 5 and 6 but NOT 2 and 3.

I am not sure how to continue tweaking it further, any suggestions?
I would like to capture the preceding boolean meaning of the tag (eg: ~) as well please.
If you have any suggestions to pre-process the string in Java before regex that would make it simpler, I am open to that possibility as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to match an optional `~` followed by an `@` and get iterative matches for group 1. You could make use of the `\G` anchors, which matches either at the start, or at the end of the previous match.

```
(?:"(?=.*"$)|\G(?!^))(~?@\w+(?:,~?@\w+)*)"?[,\h]?
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `"(?=.*"$)` Match `"` and assert that the string ends with `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `~?@\w+(?:,~?@\w+)*` Match an optional `~`, than `@` and 1+ word characters and repeat 0+ times with a comma prepended
- `)"?` Close group 1 and match an optional `"`
- `[,\h]` Match either a comma or a horizontal whitespace char.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Pn4z8/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/bI2mni)

*Example code*

```
String regex = "(?:\"(?=.*\"$)|\\G(?!^))(~?@\\w+(?:,~?@\\w+)*)\"?[,\\h]?";
String string = "\"@smoke\"\n"
     + "\"@smoke,@Functional1\"\n"
     + "\"@smoke,@Functional1,@Functional2\"\n"
     + "\"@smoke\",\"@Functional1\"\n"
     + "\"@smoke\",\"~@Functional1\"\n"
     + "\"~@smoke\",\"~@Functional1\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

*Output*

```
@smoke
@smoke,@Functional1
@smoke,@Functional1,@Functional2
@smoke
@Functional1
@smoke
~@Functional1
~@smoke
~@Functional1
```

**Edit**

If there are no consecutive matches, you could also use:

```
"(~?@\w+(?:,~?@\w+)*)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sn5Oye/1)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, looks good but I cant quite figure out the role of the `[.\h] at the end, obviously it does not work without it but I dont understand why it is needed...

Comment: It is there, so the `\G` can continue the match. If it can not, the match stops. It matches either `.` or `\h`. Then it goes back to the alternation again, where it can not match `"`, but this assertion is true `\G(?!^)` and the match continues again with `(~?@\w+)`

Comment: Actually, I just realized that second example, of the OR (lines 2, 3), I need to capture them as a single multi tags expression, otherwise they are indistinguishable from the AND - I need to know it is an OR so need to keep those together. Is that possible?

Comment: Given above explanation, I just realized line 1 is not even captured, and the solution depends on the space or a comma at the end - I should have explained (will update the question now) that the commants in brackets like (OR condition) is just there to tell the sample inputs apart, they are not really going to be part of the string input for the regex! Input will stop at the last `"`  character!

Comment: @Carmageddon If the second and third values should be one group, and the line has to end with a double quote `(?:"|\G(?!^))(?=.*"$)(~?@\w+(?:,~?@\w+)*)"?[,\h]?`  https://regex101.com/r/CtpPz5/1

Comment: Thank you! The last one was perfect, but I am still having a hard time understanding the roles of ` \G(?!^)` and `[,\h]?` in this regex, exactly.. I am reading their description, and it makes no sense to me yet.. the first one does not even look for any characters..

Comment: Thanks again! what do you mean by "consecutive matches" for the simpler regex? it seems to work as well on the sample input.